# Searching a nested structure. Can not retrieve parents with all corresponding childs

Tags: solr

The data is imported with the data import handler:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
       ...
    />
    <!-- product import -->
    <document>
        <!-- entity = table -->
        <entity name="skn" pk="SKN" rootEntity="true" query="select * from skn">
            <field column="SKN" name="id" />
            <field column="root" name="root" />
            <field column="SEARCHDESCRIPTION" name="SEARCHDESCRIPTION" />
            <entity name="sku" child="true" query="select * from sku where SKN = '${skn.SKN}'">
                <field column="SKU" name="id" />
                <field column="variant1" name="variant1" />
                <field column="variant2" name="variant2" />
                <field column="v1_long" name="v1_long" />
                <field column="v2_long" name="v2_long" />
                <field column="v1_type" name="v1_type" />
                <field column="v2_type" name="v2_type" />
            </entity>       
        </entity>
    <propertyWriter 
        dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
        type="SimplePropertiesWriter" 
        directory="conf" 
        filename="dataimport.properties" 
        locale="de-DE" 
    />
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I can get all childs for a certain parent or all parents for a certain child (so the nested structure is working). But I cannot retrive parents with the corresponding childs.

I tried the following query:

```
q={!parent which="id:1"}&fl=*,[child]&rows=200
```

It returns the parent document but not the corresponding child. I dont't get any error message. I also checked the log file.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Hi, You need have a separate field which separates parents and child. Lets say doc_type. Parents may have doc_type=parent and child as doc_type=child.
Your query becomes..

q={!parent which="doc_type:parent"}&fl=*,[child]&rows=200

Comment: Hi raghu777, I tried to add a doc_type field, but I am still unable to get the child documents. My query is: q={!parent which=doc_type:parent}&fl=*,[child]&rows=200. I still get all parents, but not a single child. On the other hand, I can get all childs for a certain product with this query: q={!child%20of=doc_type:parent}searchdescription:jacke&start=0&rows=200. I am perplexed.

Comment: I experience same thing when using schema with _nest_path_ , I got parent and children both in one query after removing _nest_path from the schema file, and i need to use [child parentFilter=""] query to get children

Comment: Hey Jigar, this worked for me! I keep the question open because it would be nice to know why it does not work with the nest_path field, but for now I can live with the solution you provided. So, thank you very much.

Comment: you know what, i am also trying to understand why it does not work with nested path, i have posted question in solr-forum and also in stackoverflow, waiting for answer.!!